# MS Word: Excessive space between separator and footnotes

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, styles, footnote

I'm using a template to write my thesis on MS Word and I'm having a problem with the footnotes. Whenever I insert one, too much space is left blank between the separating line and the text of the footnote itself, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

I'm already quite close to finishing the thesis, so ideally the solution shouldn't involve using another template or restyling the file myself from scratch in a new blank document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. Go to the View tab, then choose Draft.
> 2. Go to the References tab and click Show Footnotes.
> 3. In the drop-down list that appears in the Footnotes area, choose Footnote Separator.
> 4. Delete any extra spaces, carriage returns etc. It’s handy to have “show non-printing characters” switched on.
> 5. Repeat for the other one – I think it was Continuous Footnote Separator.
> 6. Go back to View and switch back to Print Layout.

---

source:
https://krysjez.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/quick-fix-space-before-footnotes-in-ms-word/

---

Or

> When viewing the footnote separator (in the footnotes pane),
> right-click and select Paragraph from the context menu. In the
> Paragraph dialog box, click the Indents and Spacing tab, and make sure
> that Spacing Before is set to zero. You may also want to change the
> Line Spacing to "Single."
>
> Also, to make sure no blank paragraphs is included with the separator, click the ¶ button on the Home tab. Paragraph marks are
> represented by pilcrows, ¶. Delete any excessive paragraphs if
> present.

---

Source
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-word/how-can-i-remove-the-space-above-the-footnote/6bcb9853-74d9-41c0-afd3-9a5c3394171c?auth=1

Comment: This was the first result in google, I am not sure if you tried it yet. I do not have word on this PC so I cannot test it.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing) and make sure you "block quote" quoted material ([Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help)). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: It did not work for me, still have the big space. But this was helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5aliyl2Kpc